# Gaussian integral of a function with nonzero mean

Tags: definite-integrals

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), for a Gaussian integral of an analytic function we have that

[image]

I'm trying to obtain a similar formula when there is a linear term in the Gaussian (ie the Gaussian has a nonzero mean).

My guess is that
$$
\int f(x) \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + B^T x \right) d^n x = \\
= \sqrt{\frac{(2 \pi)^n}{\det A}} \exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( B^T + \frac{d}{dx_i} \right) A^{-1} \left( B^T + \frac{d}{dx_j} \right) \right] f(x) \bigg|_{x=0}
$$

but I can't prove it. Is this equation correct? How can I prove it?